# How to get the calculation examples in analytical mechanics using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am studying analytical mechanics recently, but I find that there are few examples of analytical mechanics in my community. Where can I get the calculation examples of analytical mechanics using Mathematica?

For example 1:
[image]

```
ClearAll["`*"]
s = NDSolve[{2 x''[
        t] + (φ''[
          t] Cos[φ[
           t]] - (φ'[t])^2 Sin[φ[t]]) == 
     0, φ''[t] + x''[t] Cos[φ[t]] + 
      10 Sin[φ[t]] == 0, x[0] == φ[0] == 0, 
    x'[0] == 0, φ'[0] == 2}, {x, φ}, {t, 20}];


ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
   {x[t], -Cos[φ[t]]} /. s, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

**Or**

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
s = NDSolve[{Expand /@ 
    EulerEquations[
     10 Cos[θ[t]] + y'[t]^2 + 1/2 θ'[t]^2 + 
      y'[t] θ'[t] Cos[θ[t]], {y[t], θ[t]}, t], 
   y[0] == θ[0] == 0, 
   y'[0] == 0, θ'[0] == 2}, {y, θ}, {t, 0, 20}]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@
   {y[t], -Cos[θ[t]]} /. s, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

The ball 1 is set on the smooth horizontal bar. Now give the ball 2 an initial velocity v, and the trajectory of the ball B is as follows:

[image]

example 2:

[image]

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
L = 1;
m1 = 1; m2 = 1; g = 9.8;
s = NDSolve[{EulerEquations[
    1/2 m1*(x'[t])^2 + 1/2 m1*D[L*Sin[θ[t]], t]^2 + 
     1/2 m2*D[x[t] + L*Cos[θ[t]], t]^2 - 
     m1*g*L*Sin[θ[t]], {θ[t], x[t]}, t], θ'[0] ==
     0, θ[0] == Pi/4, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[θ[t] == 
     0, θ'[t] -> -θ'[t]]}, {θ[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 
   10}]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], Sin[θ[t]]} /. s, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I need a lot of examples of analytical mechanics like above and Mathematica code to improve the learning quality.

Comment: It is hard for anybody to answer this unless you give some examples of what you are looking for. Please be more precise.

Comment: You really need to give examples. No one can read minds here to understand exactly what you are looking for. But if you check the Wolfram demonstration web site, there are thousands of demos under mechanics, and over 100 under "analytical mechanics".

Comment: @Nasser I've updated my questions.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes  although i never used it, i know there is a book called "classical mechanics with mathematica 2° edition" that through the publisher website provide mathematica notebooks written by the author (link :http://extras.springer.com/2018/978-3-319-77595-1)

Comment: @Alucard Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need a lot of examples of analytical mechanics like above and
>   Mathematica code to improve the learning quality.

These are collection of links on this subject

1. https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=analytical%20mechanics  which contains over 100 demo on the subject., as well as https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=mechanics  which contains over 1,800 demos on mechanics.
2. book, Classical Mechanics with Mathematica

[image: Mathematica graphics]

3. book Mathematica for Theoretical Physics, Classical Mechanics and Nonlinear Dynamics

[image: Mathematica graphics]

4. book Mechanics and Dynamical Systems with Mathematica

[image: Mathematica graphics]

5. Book Mathematica in Theoretical Physics: Selected Examples from Classical Mechanics to Fractals

[image: Mathematica graphics]

6. Book A Mathematica Manual for Engineering Mechanics

[image: Mathematica graphics]

7. Book Mathematica for Physics

[image: Mathematica graphics]

8. https://mathematica-handbook.com/  handbook comes with course in Physics all done using Mathematica. Using Mathematica for Physics including mechanics.
9. [Page with Mathematica demos including mechanics](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/mma_demos/index.htm)
10. [Page with derivation of equation of motion for double pendulum Using Magthematgica](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/double_pendulum/main.html)
11. Book   Nonlinear Control and Analytical Mechanics: A Computational Approach "A CD-ROM provides extensive examples and exercises using Mathematica notebooks and programs."

[image: Mathematica graphics]

12. Book ANALYTICAL MECHANICS OF SPACE SYSTEMS "Mathematica toolboxes arc provided for rigid body kinematics routines and basic two-body orbital mechanics routines"

[image: Mathematica graphics]